# How to access an objects value when its key will be dynamically obtained while sending it as a mongodb query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an object as follows.
cityConfiguration -

```
{
 _id: 62e135519567726de42421c2,
configType: 'cityConfig'
'16': {
        cityName: 'Delhi',
        metro: true,
        tier1: true
      },
'17': {
        cityName: 'Indore',
        metro: false,
        tier1: false
      }
}
```

I have another table called BusDetails with fields like - [cityId, revenue, tax...]. Example document -

```
{ 
                    "busNumber": "KA25D5057",  
                    "cityId": "17", 
                    "revenue": 46594924, 
                    "totalCollection": 3456342
                    "tax": "2906",  
                    "passengerCount": 40
                    ......
}
```

I want to do an aggregation ($project) on the BusDetails table such that I take the cityId from that BusDetails document and if that cityId is a metro city (according to the cityConfig object) then I will return 0 or 1. I have designed the below code but its not working. How to fix it.

```
return await BsDetails.aggregate([
  {
        $match: { busNumber: 'KA25D5057' }
  },
  {
        $project: {
                   totalCollection: 1,
                   passengerCount: 1,
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   metro: {"$cond": [ cityPassConfig["$cityId"].metro == true, 1, 0]},
                  }
  }
]);
```

So for ex, in the above code, the cityId is 17 which is a non-metro city. So the "metro" field should store 0. Here I am facing problem in

```
cityPassConfig["$cityId"].metro
```

this particular statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using objects with dynamic field name is generally considered as anti-pattern and should be avoided since it introduces unnecessary complexity into queries. Nevertheless, you can use `$objectToArray` to achieve what you want.

```js
db.BusDetails.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      busNumber: "KA25D5057"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      // put your object here
      "cityConfiguration": {
        _id: ObjectId("62e135519567726de42421c2"),
        configType: "cityConfig",
        "16": {
          cityName: "Delhi",
          metro: true,
          tier1: true
        },
        "17": {
          cityName: "Indore",
          metro: false,
          tier1: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      // convert into array of k-v tuples
      "cityConfiguration": {
        "$objectToArray": "$cityConfiguration"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "cityConfiguration": {
        // iterate through the array and get the matched cityConfiguration entry
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$cityConfiguration",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.k",
                  "$cityId"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.v",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      totalCollection: 1,
      passengerCount: 1,
      metro: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": "$cityConfiguration.metro",
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sVMRc5XfzVa) for your reference.